# Strange redirect loop issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I'm getting a very odd redirect issue on my server. URL's without a trailing slash are being redirected to a URL with a trailing slash. The problem is that URL then redirects infinitely to itself.

e.g.:

http://new.whitehardt.com/services/commercials/  - works fine

but

http://new.whitehardt.com/services/commercials   - redirects to
`http://new.whitehardt.com/services/commercials/`  which in turn causes a redirect loop

I've checked .htaccess which only contains the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've been searching for 2 days for a solution to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you turn on a `RewriteLog` location and set `RewriteLogLevel 9`?  Doesn't look like Apache should be redirecting, based on the config you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that it's a `301` redirect and not a `302`.  You might be able to find the offending line with a bit of grep magic.

```
grep -Eir "R=301|redirect permenent" /etc/apache2/
```

Substitute `/etc/httpd/` if you're on a RedHat-derived distro.

Failing that, it might be part of one of the PHP files.  A similar grep for "header" in your DocumentRoot might find it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, forgive my ignorance but where would I run that code for grep? (add it .htaccess, shell, etc?)

Comment: That's a shell command.  You'll want to use SSH to connect to your server and then run that.  If your local machine is Windows, PuTTY seems to be the default choice of SSH client.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought but just wanted to be sure. Just ran it and it returned nothing.